# Memory management w/ const char * and al_get_native_file_dialog_path()

Tags: c++, char, constants, allegro5

I'm using a library function which returns a const char * variable. Below is the code:

```
if (something) {
     const char* file = get_filename();
     save(file);
}
```

Is there any need to deallocate the file variable inside the block, since it's in a block?

The function I'm using is `al_get_native_file_dialog_path()`, from allegro 5 library.

I've tried to search for any documentation on how the `const char *` variable is allocated, but nothing..

Comment: How was the string allocated?

Comment: You need to check library documentation on how to manage the returned pointer. No one here knows your library.

Comment: What does the documentation for `get_filename` say?

Comment: you have to ask the author(s) of get_filename. Its impossible to tell just by looking at the calling code

Comment: _@ventur65_ Well, at least you could find out if that memory was allocated dynamically and leaks without deleting, using a tool like valgrind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any need to deallocate the file variable inside the block, since it's in a block?

A (`const`) pointer inside a scoped block is still just a pointer.

There are no special actions taken (e.g. to automatically deallocate the memory it points to), when the scope is left.

So we can't actually tell unless knowing how that pointer was allocated by

```
const char* file = get_filename();
```

---

It could be something like

```
const char* get_filename() {
    static const char* hardcoded_stuff = "TheFileName.txt";
    return hardcoded_stuff;
}
```

or

```
const char* get_filename() {
    const char* filename = new char[MAXFILENAME];
    // ... determine and initialize filename ...
    return filename;
}
```

The first version doesn't require memory deallocation from the client side, while the second one does.

---

> I'm using a library function ...

Indicates you are using some code that isn't under your control. So you have to attend the documentation of that library, or ask the authors.

---

> I've tried to search for any documentation on how the const char * variable is allocated, but nothing..

Well, did you check their [example in the documentation](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_get_native_file_dialog_path#)?

I didn't spot any code to deallocate the pointer obtained with `al_get_native_file_dialog_path()`.

Comment: The function I'm using is al_get_native_file_dialog_path(), from allegro library. I've tried to search for any documentation on how the const char * variable is allocated, but nothing..

Comment: @ventur65 _... but nothing._ Well, what about [`al_get_native_file_dialog_path()`](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_get_native_file_dialog_path) from their documentation? I can't spot any memory deallocation from their example code.

Comment: @ventur65 If you take a look at the [source](https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/blob/93e25245d7bfa77f2f3248fba738a8958189d582/addons/native_dialog/dialog.c), you can see that `al_get_native_file_path()` returns a pointer to a a field of the dialog. The dialog will retain ownership of the path.